# Cálculo de porcentagem javascript

Tags: javascript, html, matemática, porcentagem

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e preciso calcular a porcentagem de spread(lucro em cima da venda) exemplo:
(1 eth): 107.178552387 que no caso é $107.18 com um spread de 5% (ou seja 5% de lucro em cima do preço total em eth) e logo após preciso adicionar 2.5% de taxa em cima do valor total (quantia de eth + % de spread), como eu poderia fazer isso em javascript ? a baixo um "pseudo código" em javascript para exemplificar melhor.

```js
 $(function() {
  $('#calc_input').keyup(function() {
   var x = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-unitprice')),
   y = parseFloat($(this).val()),
   cot = y * x;
   $('#resucota').attr('value', cot);
  });
 });

 $(function() {
  $('#spread').keyup(function() {
   var z = parseFloat($(this).val());
   var a = parseFloat($('#resucota').val());
   var spread = z % a;
   $('#lucro').attr('value', spread);
   var total = 2.5% + spread
   $('#resucota').attr('value', total);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="sone" style="">
    <div class="col-md-11 ">
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text unit unidade moedsele" style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">eth</span>
      </div>
      <input id="calc_input" type="text" name="total1" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg" data-unitprice="107.178552387">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">SPREAD</span>
      <input type="text" id="spread" class="form-control">
     </div>
     <hr>
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">USD</span>
      </div>
      <input readonly="" id="resucota" name="total" type="text" class="col-sm-6" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg">&nbsp;&nbsp;+ 2.5% taxa
     </div>

     <br>
     <div class="invertable-input">
      <div class="suporte">
       <div class="status_grupo">
        <div class="status_titulo m treecolun">Mínimo</div>
        <input id="min" disabled="" value="134.39278008" class="status_valor m treecolun">
        <div class="status_titulo m treecolun">USD</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br><br>
     <div class="invertable-input">
      <div class="suporte">
       <div class="status_grupo">
        <div class="status_titulo m treecolun">Lucro</div>
        <input disabled="" id="cotacao" value="0" class="status_valor m treecolun">
        <div class="status_titulo m treecolun">USD</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br><br>
     <div class="invertable-input">
      <div class="suporte">
       <div class="status_grupo">
        <div class="status_titulo m treecolun">Cotação</div>
        <input disabled="" id="cotacao" value="0" class="status_valor m treecolun">
        <div class="status_titulo m treecolun">USD</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <br><br>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd">GERAR ORDEM</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou dar um resposta baseada nas minhas interpretações:

Você quer simplesmente calcular a porcentagem, no caso, primeiro um valor em porcentagem de um valor, e em seguida em cima desse valor (`spread`) obter um novo valor. Ou seja:

```
(107.18 + 5%) + 2.5%
```

Solução: "você pode fazer isso através de matemática básica, através da multiplicação, 100% equivale a *1, 1% equivale a *0.01. Assim você poderia fazer:

```
(107.18*1.05)*1.025
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script language='JavaScript'>
function SomenteNumero(e){
    var tecla=(window.event)?event.keyCode:e.which;   
    if((tecla>47 && tecla<58)) return true;
    else{
        if (tecla== 46 || tecla==0) return true;
    else  return false;
    }
}
</script>
<html>
<head>
<br><div><center><h8>Porcentagem que a maquininha de cartão cobrou em %.</h8></br>
</center><br>
<script type="text/javascript">

function realiza_calculo()
{
    var campo1 = document.getElementById('valor1').value;
    var campo2 = document.getElementById('valor2').value;

    var maior = (parseFloat(campo1) > parseFloat(campo2)? campo1 : campo2);
    var menor = (parseFloat(campo2) < parseFloat(campo2)? campo1 : campo2);

    var result = (maior-menor)/(maior)*100;
     var result1= (result)/100
result = result.toPrecision()

 if(isNaN(result)) return 0;
    document.getElementById('resultado').value = result+"%";
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<form><center>
Valor da venda: <input type="text"autofocus=""autocomplete="off" id="valor1" value='' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'><br>
</br>
Valor recebido: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="valor2"value='' onkeypress='return SomenteNumero(event)'><br>
<br>
<strong>Resultado ==> <input type="text" id="resultado"></strong><br></br>
<center><input type="button" id="calcular" value="calcular" onclick="realiza_calculo();"><br></br><input name="BTApaga" type="reset" value="Apagar" /></p></center>
</html>
```